# Issue breakable box (tcolorbox package) with babel (layout=graphics)

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox, babel, right-to-left

This example with option `layout=graphics` produce breakable box out of page ( the non breakable one is ok). is there a solution for this issue.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paper width=5cm,paper height=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
Text text text text\par
Text text text text\par
Text text text text

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
Text text text text\par
Text text text text\par
Text text text text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox} 
Text text text text\par
Text text text text\par
Text text text text
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem seems to be from \bodydir TRT. To solve after \begin{document} write \bodydir TLT.

Comment: Problem minimal file:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paper width=5cm,paper height=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}

\bodydir TRT

\begin{document}

Text text text text

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
Text text text text\par
Text text text text\par
Text text text text
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Text text text text\par
Text text text text\par
Text text text text
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}

Comment: By changing the outer margin of your file, the output is correct!
 \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=-3.5cm,grow to right by=3.5cm]

Comment: @M.Ahmadi thanks I need a general solution which  should be done in `pgfpicture`  environment. `\bodydir TRT` is needed for RTL text.

Comment: I did not work with the babel package, I hope the following code helps. \makeatletter
\let\RTLpgfpicture\pgfpicture
\let\endRTLpgfpicture\endpgfpicture
\def\pgfpicture{\leavevmode\hskip\the\pgf@picmaxx\hskip\the\pgf@x\bgroup\RTLpgfpicture}
\def\endpgfpicture{\endRTLpgfpicture\egroup}
\makeatother